# Using "sed" to uncomment lines matching a certain pattern

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed

I'm trying to uncomment certain lines of a file, the comments start with an option that gets followed by 1 or more lines of comments. Here's a minimal example of file I'm trying to process (`example.txt`):

```
# Ignore this one
# first-option)
#   something-something x \
#       run-something-else y \
#       run-after-this z \
#       set-some-config-var 10 10

# Uncomment this one
# second-option)
#   something x \
#       run-something-else y \
#       run-something-else-again z \
#       run-after-this-something z \
#       set-some-config-var 10 10 \
#       set-some-config-var cool
```

and my naive solution (`test.sed`), by first finding the desired pattern, then applying repeated substitutions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sed

/#.*second-option/{
    s/# //; p; n;
    s/# //; p; n;
    s/# //; p; n;
    s/# //; p; n;
    s/# //; p; n;
    s/# //; p; n;
    s/# //; p; n;
}
```

output:

```bsh
$ sed -n -f test.sed example.txt
second-option)
  something x \
      run-something-else y \
      run-something-else-again z \
      run-after-this-something z \
      set-some-config-var 10 10 \
      set-some-config-var cool
```

I'm not well versed in all of  `sed`s options, but got curious if there's a more generic way of doing this (or less verbose one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this using an *address range*.  We want to start when we see `second-option` and end when we see a blank line:

```
#!/bin/sed -f

/^#.*second-option/,/^#? *$/s/^# //
#     from         |  to   | substitute
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -e '
    /^#[[:blank:]]*second-option[)]$/!b
    :a;$!N;s/\\$/&/;ta
    s/\(\n\)#/\1/g;s/^#//
  ' file
```

On a `bash` command line in `Posix sed`

Or the following with Gnu sed:

```
 $ sed -e '/^#\s*second-option[)]$/,/[^\]$/s/^#//' file
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution as well!